# Como faço para imprimir array na tela, o segmento e a localidade escolhidas, um de cada vez?

Tags: php, array, checkbox

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">

    <form method="post" action="atracoes_resultados.php">
        <h4>Escolha o Segmento:</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="ecologico"> Ecológico<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="cultural"> Cultural<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="religioso"> Religioso<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="rural"> Rural<br><br>

        <h4>Escolha a Localidade:</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="cidade"> Cidade<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="estrada"> Estrada AM 352<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="rio"> No Rio Negro<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="anavilhanas"> No Parque Anavilhanas<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="jau"> No Parque Jaú<br><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="enviar" />
        <input id="submeter" type="submit" value="Busca">
        </h3>
    </form>  
    <br>                            
</div><!-- form -->
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 lateral"> 
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'enviar'){        
    if(!empty($_POST['csg'])){
        $campo = $_POST['csg'];
        foreach($campo as $value){  
                $banco = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM atracoes WHERE segmento  LIKE '%$value%'"); 
                    while($lnbusca = mysql_fetch_array($banco)){    
?>
<?php

                        echo '<img src="'.$lnbusca['thumb'].'" height="50" width="150" class="img-responsive">';
                        ?>
                        <a href="emitir_recibos.php?id=<?php echo $lnbusca['id']; ?>" target="_blank"><FONT face="verdana" COLOR="#996633" class="clicavel"><?php echo $lnbusca['segmento']; ?><?php echo " e "; ?><?php echo $lnbusca['localidade']; ?></font></a>     
                        <?php
                        echo '<hr>';            

                        ?>


<?php

                    }
                            }
                                }
    else{
        echo "<h1>Atração não selecionada</h5>";
    }//-- empty --/
    }//-- isset --/
?>

</div>
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta. Quer imprimir todos os campos do vetor ou só quer mostrar os campos para saber os nomes dos índices? Na segunda opção você pode usar o var_char. Na primeira, se forem muitos dados, pode usar um "loop for" ou "foreach"

Comment: Bom dia.
O wmsouza alterou minha pergunta aumentando a dúvida minha, hehe.

Comment: Bom dia.
O wmsouza alterou minha pergunta aumentando a dúvida minha, hehe. Preciso apenas imprimir na tela, duas escolhas no checkbox (que irão buscar no banco mysql, tipo: selecionar ecologico e TAMBÉM cidade, apenas os dados com segmento e cidade, que estão no banco, aparecerão na tela). Tenho uma tabela atracoes, onde tenho duas colunas SEGMENTO e LOCALIDADE, quero que me retorne apenas os registros que contenham as escolhas pelo usuario no checkbox. espero ter melhorado a pergunta.

Comment: Alguém para me ajudar?    : (

Comment: Agora entendi! Você deve adicionar um o check Listener no checkbox (javascript puro ou jQuery) que ao ser marcado você pega o valor do checkbox e envia para uma página PHP usando Ajax. Essa página PHP faz a consulta e retorna o segmento/localidade em JSON. Dentro do Ajax que enviou os dados você consegue imprimir usando um loop. É bastante coisa...

Comment: Não use mysql_query, use PDO.

Comment: Estou iniciando php/mysql, e pensei que fosse possivel recuperar os dados SEGMENTO e LOCALIDADE simultaneamente (do checkbox no codigo acima) apenas usando a rotina acima apresentada. Ao escolher o segmento, o código imprime corretamente na tela apenas a escolha (do segmento). Já a localidade (que deveria estar vinculada á apenas 1 (hum) segmento escolhido), desaparece. Existe pelo menos uma forma de recupera-la?

Comment: Dá pra pegar eles simultaneamente na página php que recebe esse formulário, mas pra isso você precisa dar nomes diferentes aos checkbox de segmento e localidade. "csg[]" é um vetor de segmentos, dê outro nome ao de localidade. Assim, no php, você dá um $_POST nesses dois vetores

Comment: Esse formulário que está no código é estático (do jeito que está aí) ou é ele que é preenchido com os dados do SQL? Cada vez que abro a pergunta fico mais confuso haha parece algo muito simples, só preciso entender 100%

Comment: O formulário é estático, os dados constam apenas no checkbox, mas ao recupera-los, é que começa a dor de cabeça na manipulação da condição para retornar apenas o que foi clicado. O problema é que está sendo recuperado tudo do banco.

Comment: É assim: existem 4 segmentos, sendo que cada segmento é composto por todas as localidades . Se eu escolher ecológico + cidade e enviar, o desejo é de ter apenas os eventos ecologicos que ocorrerem na cidade (sendo que tb os outros três segmentos restantes tb têm eventos na cidade, mas não os quero no resultado da busca).

Comment: Aah perfeito! Adiciona a estrutura do seu banco de dados na pergunta que irei criar a resposta para você. Pode ser o SQL que cria e preenche, pra eu reproduzir aqui.

Comment: Eu não consegui editar minha pergunta, mas vou postar aqui:  banco: SEMTUR  tabela: atracoes.                                                                                                id            int(5)   AUTO_INCREMENT
nome1         varchar(200) utf8_general_ci
segmento      varchar(200) utf8_general_ci
nome2         text utf8_general_ci
localidade    varchar(200) utf8_general_ci
thumb         text utf8_general_ci

Comment: se não der para entender, mando uma outra melhor.

Comment: Terminei. Eu uso PDO porque estou familiarizado, qualquer coisa é só você trocar para o que você quiser (mysqli). Vou editar e postar

Comment: No aguardo.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz uma requisição jQuery Ajax da página do formulário para o arquivo que conecta ao banco de dados. Usando o resultado em JSON para "escrever" em uma DIV.

**Página HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="eventos.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" id="form-seg-loc">
            <h4>Escolha o Segmento:</h4>
            <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="ecologico"> Ecológico<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="cultural"> Cultural<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="religioso"> Religioso<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="csg[]" value="rural"> Rural<br><br>

            <h4>Escolha a Localidade:</h4>
            <input type="checkbox" name="loc[]" value="cidade"> Cidade<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="loc[]" value="estrada"> Estrada AM 352<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="loc[]" value="rio"> No Rio Negro<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="loc[]" value="anavilhanas"> No Parque Anavilhanas<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="loc[]" value="jau"> No Parque Jaú<br><br>

            <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="enviar" />
            <input id="submeter" type="submit" value="Busca">
        </form>

        <div id="resultado-seg-loc"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

eventos.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form-seg-loc").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var dadosForm = $(this).serialize(); //nesse escopo, this é o formulário

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "atracoes_resultados.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: dadosForm,
            success: function (response) {
                var res = "";

                $.each(response.resultados, function(item){

                    //this é a posição atual do json
                    res += "<p>Nome 1: " + this.nome1 + "</p>" +
                        "<p>Segmento: " + this.segmento + "</p>" +
                        "<p>Nome 2: " + this.nome2 + "</p>" +
                        "<p>Localidade: " + this.localidade + "</p>" +
                        "<hr>";

                });

                $("#resultado-seg-loc").html(res);

            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.error(response);
                alert('Erro na requisição dos dados. Atualize a página');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**connect_db.php**:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=SEMTUR; charset=utf8;", "USUARIO", "SENHA", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

**atracoes_resultados.php:**

```
<?php

require_once("connect_db.php"); //informe o caminho do arquivo caso não esteja no mesmo diretório

$seg = isSet($_POST["csg"]) ? $_POST["csg"] : null;
$loc = isSet($_POST["loc"]) ? $_POST["loc"] : null;

//caso o usuário não envie nada, pára a página
if($seg == null && $loc == null){
    exit();
}

/* MONTA A QUERY */
$optseg = "SELECT * FROM `atracoes` WHERE (";

//parte da consulta para SEGMENTO
if($seg != null){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($seg); $i++){
        $optseg .= "segmento = \"" . $seg[$i]."\"";
        if($i < count($seg)-1)
            $optseg .= " OR ";
        else
            $optseg .= ")";
    }
}

//condição para saber se é preciso adicionar um AND na consulta
if($seg != null && $loc != null){
    $optseg .= " AND (";
}

//parte da consulta para LOCALIDADE
if($loc != null){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($loc); $i++){
        $optseg .= "localidade = \"" . $loc[$i]."\"";
        if($i < count($loc)-1)
            $optseg .= " OR ";
        else
            $optseg .= ")";
    }
}

$query = $db->prepare($optseg);

$query->execute();
$resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode(
    array(
    "resultados" => $resultado
    )
);
?>
```

Com base nas informações fornecidas esse código resolve o problema com algumas adaptações devido a limitação do que pôde ser informado.

Comment: Fiz tudo como o Jhonatan me orientou, de tudo certo!!! Resolvido meu problema, obrigado. Stackoverflow é top!!!